# Best way to relate multiple rows across tables

Tags: mysql

I want to know the best practice for relating one row in one table, to multiple rows in another table.

Let's say I have the following two tables:

```
table_users
id    | username
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | user1
2     | user2
3     | user3

table_texts
id    | text
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | This is a secret text, that only user2 and user3 should see.
```

Now my only solution is to create a third table:

```
table_user_text_relation
id    | text_id    | user_id
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 1          | 2
2     | 1          | 3
```

And then select like this:

```
SELECT
    table_texts.text 

FROM
    table_users, table_texts, table_user_text_relation

WHERE
    table_users.id = table_user_text_relation.user_id
    AND
    table_texts.id = table_user_text_relation.text_id
```

And that is fine... However, if I have 6000 users each with access to 500 texts, table_user_text_relation would then have to have 3.000.000 rows to establish many to many relationships?

Is there a better / smarter way to do this?

Comment: MySQL will easily handle 3 mln rows. Just establish indexes in users_to_texts table. There is nothing to improve here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.  I have been searching a long time and having a match table is the best way.  Because the match table only uses ints, it doesn't take up to much room.  I would say this is the best practice.